# laravel broadcast channel is not calling after changing auth endpoint

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo, pusher-js

i am developing teacher and student chat system in laravel and vuejs using pusher. So as i read from documentation that laravel by default do the user authentication for private and presence channel so both my model are different one is student and other one is teacher both are not extend from Authenticatable so what i did is change the authendpoint and make a new route and return the pusher ath:key i,m successfully doing that but now the problem is after returning auth response Echo.private is not calling my channel

This is my Channel.php file code

```
Broadcast::channel('student-messages.{id}', function($id) {
    return true;
},['guards'=>['web']]);
```

This is my chat app file code

```
window.Echo.private(`student-messages.${this.student.id}`)
     .listen('NewMessage',(e)=>{
         console.log(e);
     });
```

This is my route in web.php

```
Route::post('/custom/endpoint/auth',function (Request $request){ 
    $pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'), env('PUSHER_APP_ID')); 
    return $pusher->socket_auth($request->request->get('channel_name'),$request->request->get('socket_id')); 
 });
```

Comment: Consider pasting the code samples using built in formattd code options instead of images. Include error messages as well.

Comment: i have added code samples rather then screenshot